# Scope with argument for a json column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a json column - `document`.

I have specified the `color_code` attribute with `store_accessor :document, :color_code`

I can successfully query all instances for the number 3:

```
MyModel.where("document ->> 'color_code' = '3'")
```

But how would I convert that query to a scope with a number argument, so I can use it more generally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
class MyModel
   scope :with_color, ->(color) { where("document ->> 'color_code' = '?'", color) }
end
```

and then issue the scope:

```
MyModel.with_color(3)
```